# Power BI enable service in Azure

Tags: azure

I want to enable Power BI service in Azure. What are the steps or requirements to be followed to enable power BI service in Azure

Answer (score 1):

The Power BI service needs to be registered with the Azure Active Directory you're using.  To do that 2 things need to happen. First you need an AAD user in that directory. Second, that user needs to sign-up for Power BI.  Detailed steps are here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186542.aspx

Update: there are now application registration links on https://dev.powerbi.com that make it really easy.

Be aware, don't forget the very last "sign-in to power bi" step - it's the one people forget.

This is required because when a user in you AAD uses Power BI for the first time, the service is registered in AAD so the Permissions associated with the service are then displayed for Apps you register.  Miss that step and you'll never find the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI is not an Azure service.  You create Power BI accounts at powerbi.com and you connect Azure services to Power BI like explained in this Power BI documentation page: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-azure-and-power-bi/

Comment: i want to connect app data using Power BI APIs , for that in Azure i have to select  Power BI Service. But in Azure i am not able to find the Power BI Service. To bring that Power BI Service what should i do.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to register your app with Azure Active Directory,you need to visit this link [Register an App](https://dev.powerbi.com/apps) . Once you visit the link you need to follow these steps.

1.Login to your Power BI account
2. Tell us about your app (App Name, App Type, Redirect URL and Home Page URL)
3. Choose API to access (DataSet API's, Report and Dashboard API's and other API's)
4. After providing the above details you need to click on the register app button that will provide you a Client ID and Client-secret ID. Also, this process will automatically enable the Power Bi service in Azure Active Directory, You can check it in the Azure portal.